RDS in the same security group does not allow connection whilst another does
I had a similar issue with EC2 (not solved yet: SSH to EC2 times out, but other instances in the same security group are reachable) and here is the same with RDS.
I have existing RDS running with SG attached to it. The SG allows only certain IPs, including my VPN connection.
I created a new RDS instance in the same VPC and attached the same existing SG to it. Public access is on.
And I still can connect to the old instance. The new one refuses connections, I get timeouts.
NMAP tells that the 3306 is filtered for that instance when I try to connect. Telnet throws a timeout.
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-04-17 13:19 CEST
Nmap scan report for ec2-<>.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (<>)
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql

And if I add inbound 0.0.0.0/0 to existing security group I can connect to the new instance. And NMAP shows 3306 as opened.
So the question is why the same SG behaves differently for different instances. I'm puzzled.

Your question can't be answered with the information provided. If you want help you will need to provide precise information about configurations of instances and security groups. One thing to note is two resources in a security group can't automatically communicate, you need a self-referential security group - ie the security group ingress section must specify itself as an allowed source of traffic.
